# Verificar si existe un servidor mysql en red con CMD?

Tags: mysql, cmd, inno-setup

Estoy tratando de crear un instalador con [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) el cual instala un Servidor o Terminal de un punto de venta, el problema es que cuando instalo una terminal necesito verificar si existe la base de datos en el `Host` especificado (Servidor) para poder avanzar.

La manera que logre y se acerca a lo que quiero hacer es ejecutando el `mysqldump.exe`:

```
mysqldump.exe -uroot -pjavac -P3500 -h10.1.12.79 baseDatos
```

El problema que tengo es que no quiero crear un respaldo, solo necesito comprobar si existe la base o no, con algun programa de linea de comandos ligero.

Hay alguna herramienta que pueda comprobar la existencia de una base de datos y pueda correrla por `CMD` similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [`mysql`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html) así por ejemplo:

```
mysql.exe --host=HOST --user=USER --password=PASS --execute="SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'DB_NAME'"
```

Si la base:

- **No existe** el resultado sera vació.
- **Si existe**, devolverá una fila.

Comment: Muchas gracias,

Comment: Existe alguna manera de acomodarlo para que si existe me devuelva 0 y si no existe devuelva cualquier otro?